# oauth2-proxy: Validate Azure AD JWT Token returns 401

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jwt, oauth2-proxy

I am trying to validate JWT Token with [oauth2-proxy](https://github.com/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy/tree/master) and Azure AD (multi tenant). The setup is working and I can log in via `http://localhost:4180`. This is how I run the proxy:

```bash
docker run --net=host quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:latest \
--provider=oidc \
--oidc-issuer-url=https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0 \
--insecure-oidc-skip-issuer-verification=true \
--scope=[REDACTED] \
--oidc-email-claim=preferred_username \
--email-domain="*" \
--client-secret=[REDACTED] \
--client-id=[REDACTED] \
--cookie-secret=[REDACTED] \
--redirect-url="http://localhost:8080" \
--pass-access-token=true \
--pass-authorization-header=true \
--upstream=file:///dev/null \
--pass-user-headers=true \
--auth-logging=true \
--standard-logging=true \
--request-logging=true
```

I made a small NextJS application with React MSAL so I can get my JWT token. I even verified it at https://jwt.io and everything looks okay.

Problem occurs when I want to check validity of token. I send a request to `http://localhost:4180/oauth2/auth` via *Insomnia* and add the `Authorization`: `Bearer <token>` header, but I constantly get 401.

[image]

How can I get 202 and the token accepted? What am I doing wrong? I can not any information as to what `oauth2/auth` expects from me. Again, I am certain the token is valid, but I do not know how to pass it to `oauth2/auth`.

I am open to any solutions to validate this JWT token. I just want to either get 202 or 401. The final solution will be connected to *nginx*.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be Authentication rather it should be Authorization.
For Eg: Authorization: 'Bearer Token'

Also if trying from UI, /oauth2/auth will always return 401 if not authenticated.So First login to the host_url and then try {host_url}/oauth2/auth. It will give 202 or 401 based on the session.

Also it gives you an auth file which contains token, cookie etc as configured